# Capybara field.has_css? matcher

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest

I'm using following spec with `MiniTest::Spec` and `Capybara`:

```
find_field('Email').must_have_css('[autofocus]')
```

to check if the field called 'Email' has the `autofocus` attribute. The [doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method) says following:

> has_css?(path, options = {})
>
> Checks if a given CSS selector is on the page or current node.

As far as I understand, field 'Email' is a node, so calling `must_have_css` should definitely work! What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got an answer by [Jonas Nicklas](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

> No, it shouldn't work. has_css? will check if any of the *descendants*
>   of the element match the given CSS. It will not check the element
>   itself. Since the autofocus property is likely on the email field
>   itself, has_css? will always return false in this case.
>
> You might try:
>
> ```
> find_field('Email')[:autofocus].should be_present
> ```
>
> this can also be done with XPath, but I can't recall the syntax off
>   the top of my head.

---

My solution:

```
find_field('Email')[:autofocus].must_equal('autofocus')
```

Comment: Though I understand @jnicklas' argument that ```has_css?``` should only apply to descendants, it would be great to have an ```is?``` matcher (similar to [jQuery.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)) that applies to the current element.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/3976287 for monkey patch that adds ```match_selector?``` and ```match_css?``` matchers.  Original code could be written as ```find_field('Email').must_match_css('[autofocus]')``` (untested...)

Comment: [Preferred syntax is now](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/):  expect(find_field('Email')[:autofocus]).to be_present

Comment: Only if you're using rspec, which I don't like at all :P Yes, for rspec this is the preferred syntax, for minitest my answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Off top of my head. Can you use `has_selector?()`. Using Rspec wit Capy:

```
page.should have_selector('email', autofocus: true)
```

Also check Capybara matchers http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers

Comment: Do you have a CSS class declared for this email field that has `autofocus` set? If so, you can just check for `email` field with this class. Something like: `page.should have_selector('email.autofocused'). Where `autofocused` is your CSS class.
`

Comment: Autofocus is **not** CSS, it's HTML standard.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used MiniTest before but your syntax for checking for the attribute looks correct.

My concern would be with your use of find_field. The docs say:

> Find a form field on the page. The field can be found by its name, id or label text.

It looks like you are trying to find the field based on the label. If so I would check that you have the for attribute on it and and that it has the correct id of the form field you are looking for. To rule out this being the issue you could temporarily slap an id your form field and look for that explicitly.